# Running some parts of the script with root and other parts with normal user

Tags: bash, ubuntu

To make sure my bash script runs as root I use:

```
if [ "$UID" -ne "0" ]; then
echo "You must root to run $0. Try following"
echo "sudo $0"
exit 9
fi
```

But in the script, there some commands that I want to run with `sudo -u $USER`, however, if I run the whole script as root it comes out as sudo -u root ($USER will be root, not the original USER).

How do I run the script as root but also run certain commands in the script as the default logged in user so I don't have to put in the password or do `chmod` to change permissions?

Comment: You wrote "...I run the whole script as root it comes out as `sudo -u $USER`". I think you wanted to ask "I run the whole script as root it comes out as `sudo -u root` (`$USER` will be root, not the original USER)". Can you edit your question to make this clear?

Comment: @WalterA Yes, I did mean that. I have edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the non-evaluated user in some variable.

How you want to do this depends on your actual use case.

You can look at:

Nasty temp file:

```
echo "$USER" >  /tmp/thatsme.tmp
su -
# Hmm, now hope nobody has changed the tmpfile doing the same trick
orguser=$(cat /tmp/thatsme.tmp)
rm /tmp/thatsme.tmp
```

Keep environment

```
export orguser="$USER"
su # Not su -
echo "orguser=${orguser}"
```

Proces `ps -ef` and look for original user on the same tty you are on. (not recommended)

Call `su - -c script additional parameter` and change your master script that it pulls the user from `$1`.

Answer (score 0):

Within your bash script you'll need to use the 'su' command to switch user, then the -c command with your needed command/script.

If you run as root you won't need to put in the $USER password.

Example: su $USER -c "command"

Comment: But the $USER would be `root`. I want to run as the normal logged in user that is not `root`.

Comment: save you $USER before doing su -u root as su may reset this env var

Comment: There is a $SUDO_USER which returns the username of the account that made the sudo call.